# while sending mail to multiple recipients in "to" header "me" as first place

Tags: java, http-headers, jakarta-mail, sendmail, email-headers

I am sending mails to multiple people by using Java Mail Service.when i send email for list of people the "to" header is constructed as follows.

to: **saijayanth_p, me, deepu.pardhu530**

But i want the "to" header as, it need to show all other recipients mail addresses when I click drop down beside to header where only "me" must be shown by default.

to: me **drodownlink**

See the following Example.Context get clearly

```
StringBuilder toAddresses = new StringBuilder();
toAddresses.append("laxman505@gmail.com");
toAddresses.append(",");
toAddresses.append("laxman506@gmail.com");
toAddresses.append(",");
toAddresses.append("laxman507@gmail.com");
rv.addHeader("to: "+toaddresses);
```

if i am sending mail to  toAddresses list

laxman506@gmail.com recipient got mail as follows

**Actual Output**:(client side)
To laxman505@gmail.com,me,laxman506@gmail.com

**Expected Output**:(client side)
To me,laxman505@gmail.com,laxman506@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It's completely up to the mail reader how it displays the header information, there isn't anything you can do in the construction of the message to control that, and different mail readers are going to do it differently.

Comment: all recipients emails are gmail.The mentioned problem is occurring when sending mails from my application.if i send mails from any other applications it is getting fine i.e **me** as first.So i taught that any configuration or filter or any extra headers have to add for my java application.what i am thinking is it correct?

Comment: list of email addresses are concatenated to a StringBuilder and it is passing value as mail **To** header.

Comment: Please see the description once.i have added the code to get more context

Comment: If you only care about Gmail, and you can make it work as expected when sending mail using other mail programs, then compare the headers being set by those other programs with the headers being set when using JavaMail.  You'll need to look at the raw MIME source for the message to compare.  Note also that you should **not** need to use the addHeader method; use the addRecipients method instead and let JavaMail ensure that you have a properly formatted header.